# Can anyone help me resolve injector error in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use angular js for front end view in socialengine. But i am getting error. i don't know why this error is persisting.
This is my error i am getting :

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ng due to:
TypeError: Cannot set property 'aHrefSanitizationWhitelist' of null
    at $$SanitizeUriProvider (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:18428:35)
    at new <anonymous> (http://bananabook.net/externals/mootools/mootools-core-1.4.5-full-compat-yc.js?c=199:88:89)
    at Object.instantiate (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:4857:14)
    at provider (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:4666:36)
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:401:32
    at forEach (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:371:20)
    at Object.provider (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:4656:9)
    at ngModule (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:2676:16)
    at Object.invoke (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:4842:19)
    at runInvokeQueue (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:4730:35)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=ng&p1=TypeError%3A%…cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.1%2Fangular.js%3A4730%3A35)
    at $$SanitizeUriProvider (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:18428:35)
    at new <anonymous> (http://bananabook.net/externals/mootools/mootools-core-1.4.5-full-compat-yc.js?c=199:88:89)
    at Object.instantiate (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:4857:14)
    at provider (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:4666:36)
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:401:32
    at forEach (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:371:20)
    at Object.provider (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:4656:9)
    at ngModule (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:2676:16)
    at Object.invoke (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:4842:19)
    at runInvokeQueue (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:4730:35)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=ng&p1=TypeError%3A%…cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.6.1%2Fangular.js%3A4730%3A35)
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:68:12
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:4759:15
    at forEach (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:357:20)
    at loadModules (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:4720:5)
    at createInjector (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:4642:19)
    at doBootstrap (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:1838:20)
    at bootstrap (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:1859:12)
    at angularInit (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:1744:5)
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:32977:5
    at HTMLDocument.trigger (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js:3314:5)
```

This is the code i have used:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module("app",['ngSanitize']);

    app.controller("AppController",function($scope,$sce) {
        $scope.Videos = [{
    chapter_name : "XXXXX",
    chapter_content : [{
    video_name : "XXXXX",
    Description : "XXXXX",
    video_id : "pWj1WkzhCiI",
    },video_name : "XXXX",
    Description : "xxxx",
    video_id : "9fIQ_Tp-omk",
    }],{
    chapter_name : "XXXXX",
    chapter_content : [{
    video_name : "XXXXX",
    Description : "XXXXX",
    video_id : "pWj1WkzhCiI",
    }]

}];
    $scope.toggle = [];
    $scope.togglefunction = function(index){
        if($scope.toggle[index]){
            $scope.toggle[index] = false;
        }
        else{
            $scope.toggle[index] = true;
        }
    }

    $scope.playVideo = function(title,id,description){
      $scope.trigger = true;
      $scope.videoTitle = title;
      $scope.videoUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+id+"?rel=0&showinfo=0";
      $scope.videodescription = $sce.trustAsHtml(description);
    }
     $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
  }

  $scope.trigger1 = true;

  $scope.trigger2 = {
    "padding-left" : "8px",
    "margin-left" : "20px",
    "postion" : "absolute",
    "max-height": "520px",
    "overflow-y": "scroll",
    "padding-right": "5px",
  }

  $scope.opencloseside = function(){
    if($scope.trigger1){
         $scope.trigger2 = {
    "padding-left" : "18px",
    "margin-left" : "120px",
    "postion" : "absolute",
    "max-height": "520px",
    "overflow-y": "scroll",
    "padding-right": "5px",
  }
        $scope.trigger1 = false;
    }
    else{
      $scope.trigger1 = true;
    }
  }


    });
</script>   
<style>

div.accordion {

    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: .95em .7rem;
    padding-top: 0.95em;
    padding-right: 0.7rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.95em;
    padding-left: .47rem;
    padding-left: .47rem;
    width: 64%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-top: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}

div.accordion.active, div.accordion:hover {

    color: #007aff;
}

div.panel {
    padding-left:20%;
    padding: 0 18px;
    display: none;
}
a.video_page_a {
    color: black;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.video_page_li {  
    padding:12px;

    color: black;
    border-top: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
}
li.video_page_li:hover , li.video_page_li:active {

    cursor :pointer;

}
div.panel.show {
    display: block;
span.greatertoggle {
   display:none;
}
}
.video_page_ul{
padding-left: 5%;
list-style:none;}
video_page_a.active{
background-color:red;}
#sidemenubutton {
   width:250px;;position:absolute;background-color: white;
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  #sidemenubutton {
    width:98%;position:absolute;background-color: white;
}
</style>

<div ng-app="app">
    <div style="width: 100%;" ng-controller="AppController">
      <div style="float:left;height:100%;width: 20%;max-height:520px;overflow-y:scroll;" ng-show="trigger1">
        <div id="sidemenubutton"><button style="width:60px;padding:0px;background:white;border:0px solid white" ng-click="opencloseside()"><img src="http://bananabook.net/public/admin/sidemenuicon.png" style="width:50px;"></button></div>
            <br><div ng-repeat="videos in Videos">
            <div class="accordion" ng-click="togglefunction($index)">{{videos.chapter_name}}</div>
            <div ng-show="toggle[$index]">
              <ul class="video_page_ul">
                <li ng-repeat="vid in videos.chapter_content" ng-click="playVideo(vid.video_name,vid.video_id,vid.Description)" class="video_page_li">{{vid.video_name}}</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       <button style="width:60px;padding:0px;background:white;border:0px solid white" ng-click="opencloseside()"><img src="http://bananabook.net/public/admin/sidemenuicon1.png" style="width:60px;position:absolute;top:50px;left:0px;" ng-show="!trigger1"></button>
      <div  ng-show="trigger"  ng-style="trigger2">
        <h1>{{videoTitle}}</h1>
         <iframe  src="{{trustSrc(videoUrl)}}" width="560" height="315" /></iframe>
         <h3>Description</h3>
          <span ng-bind-html="videodescription"></span>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't why i am getting this error. Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you run this code without min.js? And show us full error.

Comment: i have update question as you have asked. can you please check it again

Comment: Why is `http://bananabook.net/externals/mootools/mootools-core-1.4.5-full-compat-yc.js` in the stack trace? Where was that file added?

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue when migrating from 1.2.32 to 1.8.2.
There is one change in the name. 'aHrefSanitizationWhitelist' is now 'aHrefSanitizationTrustedUrlList'.

Answer (score 0):

not able to add comments...

Use non-minified version of angular, then when you see that error in console, its a link to error details, click on that link in console. it should redirect you to angular website which will show you exact error details, that should help you in solving the issue.

Though the link is still there even with minified version, but due to name mangling you wont get exact name, hence do it with non-minified version

Answer (score 0):

There were some errors in your code, check the updated code below and refresh the page using ctrl +f5

```
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("app",['ngSanitize']);

        app.controller("AppController",function($scope,$sce) {
            $scope.Videos = [{
                chapter_name : "XXXXX",
                chapter_content : [{
                        video_name : "XXXXX",
                        Description : "XXXXX",
                        video_id : "pWj1WkzhCiI",
                    },
                    {
                        video_name : "XXXX",
                        Description : "xxxx",
                        video_id : "9fIQ_Tp-omk",
                    },
                    {
                        chapter_name: "XXXXX",
                        chapter_content: [{
                            video_name: "XXXXX",
                            Description: "XXXXX",
                            video_id: "pWj1WkzhCiI",
                        }]
                    }]

            }];
            $scope.toggle = [];
            $scope.togglefunction = function(index){
                if($scope.toggle[index]){
                    $scope.toggle[index] = false;
                }
                else{
                    $scope.toggle[index] = true;
                }
            }

            $scope.playVideo = function(title,id,description){
                $scope.trigger = true;
                $scope.videoTitle = title;
                $scope.videoUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+id+"?rel=0&showinfo=0";
                $scope.videodescription = $sce.trustAsHtml(description);
            }
            $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
                return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
            }

            $scope.trigger1 = true;

            $scope.trigger2 = {
                "padding-left" : "8px",
                "margin-left" : "20px",
                "postion" : "absolute",
                "max-height": "520px",
                "overflow-y": "scroll",
                "padding-right": "5px",
            }

            $scope.opencloseside = function(){
                if($scope.trigger1){
                    $scope.trigger2 = {
                        "padding-left" : "18px",
                        "margin-left" : "120px",
                        "postion" : "absolute",
                        "max-height": "520px",
                        "overflow-y": "scroll",
                        "padding-right": "5px",
                    }
                    $scope.trigger1 = false;
                }
                else{
                    $scope.trigger1 = true;
                }
            }


        });
    </script>
```

Comment: $scope.videos array of objects was not properly formatted.Is above solution working for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your config file. Add `$compileProvider` to your config structure.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$compileProvider', function($routeProvider, $compileProvider) {

    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension):/);

}]);
```